# how to use like on a long string value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like, phone-number

I'm trying to use LIKE statement in mysql

the values I'm trying to search are

ex:

```
(999) 999-9999
(999) 888-8888
(888) 888-8888
(888) 999-9999
```

when I'm trying to search for

`(888) or (999)`

it shows up just fine, but when I'm searching for

```
999-9999 or 888-8888
```

the values won't show

php script for database:

```
if($area != "" & $phone != ""){

         $phone = $area.' '.$phone;
         $s_phone = " AND pros_num ='$phone'";

}else if($area == "" & $phone != "")

         $s_phone = " AND pros_num LIKE '$phone%'";
else

         $s_phone = " AND pros_num LIKE '$area%'";
```

Comment: is this really the structure in your DB? Formatted phone numbers?

Comment: yes, the data is passed on by the clients.

Comment: `&` instead of `&&`? `==` instead of `===`? Non-parametrized queries?

Comment: You've written this so that it is vulnerable to SQL injection...

Comment: @Nicarus not necessarily.

Comment: @itachi - sure, the OP could be escaping the string somewhere else, either way this is not a good way to code for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wildcard is in the wrong place:

```
$s_phone = " AND pros_num LIKE '%$phone'";
```

[EDIT]
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlwhere.php will provide guidance on wildcard usage.

Answer (score 3):

You should move the percent sign.

```
AND pros_num LIKE '$phone%'";
```

becomes

```
AND pros_num LIKE '%$phone'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$s_phone = " AND pros_num LIKE '%{$phone}%'";
```

Will search the required string. Whether it has some characters before it or after it.

Or:

```
$s_phone = " AND pros_num LIKE '%{$phone}'";
```

% sign is a wildcard!

Comment: generally i hate to see it but in this case, valid. my upvote.